# Android Crop parent bitmap with the child co-ordinates

Tags: android

I have two ImageView/Bitmap, one for visible background and it not movable one, Another one is movable bitmap on the background view. The movable bitmap have pinch zoom and rotate with matrix. Finally find movable co-ordinates/rect position and crop background bitmap using those rect position. My question is how to calculate/get rect position?.

For my sample, what i need for your view. Pleas post your idea here, it help to every one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend more time to search and after few weeks for get this result.

```
private Bitmap getCroppedBmp(Bitmap childBmp, Bitmap ParentBmp) {
    // viewBmp is movable bitmap, orgBitmap is Parent Bitmap
    Bitmap viewBmp = childBmp;
    Bitmap orgBitmap = ParentBmp;

    float[] v = new float[9];
    // get Matrix from View
    cropImage.savedMatrix.getValues(v); 

    float left = v[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float top = v[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    // calculate the degree of rotation
    float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X],
            v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));

    // Rotate viewBmp
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postRotate(rAngle, viewBmp.getWidth() / 2, viewBmp.getHeight() / 2);
    Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewBmp, 0, 0, viewBmp.getWidth(),
            viewBmp.getHeight(), m, true);

    // calculate real scale
    float rScale = (float) Math
            .sqrt((v[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * v[Matrix.MSCALE_X])
                    + (v[Matrix.MSKEW_Y] * v[Matrix.MSKEW_Y]));

    // Scale viewBmp
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
    m1.postScale(rScale, rScale, width / 2, height / 2);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmap, 0, 0, width, height,
            m1, true);
    // Finally Get cropped Bitmap
    Bitmap resultingImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(orgBitmap, (int) left,
            (int) top, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight());
    return resultingImage;
}
```